# Laravel 5. wherehas с полным соотвествием many to many

Tags: php, laravel

Как реализовать получение выборке, где связанные параметры проверяются не по наличию хотя-бы одного, а если только есть все указанные. 
Например:

```
$select_filters = array(1,2,3);
$posts= Post::where('publish', $publish)->whereHas('filters', function ($query) use($select_filters ) {
                                $query->whereIn('filters.id', $select_filters );                     
                    })->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Соответственно я получаю все записи, где есть хотя-бы 1 id из $select_options. 
А мне нужно получить записи, где привязаны все фильтры (1,2,3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить несколько whereHas для этого:

```php
$query = Post::where('publish', $publish);
foreach($select_filters as $filter_id) {
    $query->whereHas('filters', function ($q) use ($filter_id) {
        $q->where('filters.id', $filter_id);
    });
}
$posts = $query->get();
```

Comment: Ну такой вариант я думал, но как-то надеялся, что можно иначе придумать. Но спасибо